# VSCode system-wide installation warning

Tags: visual-studio-code

These days, anytime I start VSCode, I get this warning

*You are running the system-wide installation of Code, while having the user-wide distribution installed as well. Make sure you're running the Code version you expect.*

Please how do I fix that?

Comment: [The best to do here, if possible, is to uninstall the global installation. All will be good then.](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/56260#issuecomment-413560803)

Comment: Simplest is to make two shortcuts and name them Local and System Wide (you'll be prompted for admin permission to rename the system wide one)

Answer (score 46, accepted):

**UPDATE** (Recommended by @Fabio Turati)

Just uninstalling the older one **without** the (USER) extension, it seems working. If not, then uninstall the one left and reinstall vscode.

**additional reading:**

You installed the new one (with USER extension) before uninstalling the older one. So now you have both, and this is why you get that message. You need to uninstall them both, then reinstall vs code. Make sure you add a shortcut on desktop, it took me a few more minutes to find the .exe of vs code. No worries you don't lose anything by uninstalling...

cheers !

Comment: Okay, that worked but I didn't uninstall both. I just uninstalled the one **without** the (USER) and I never saw the warning again. Thanks anyway.

Comment: that's what I did first but the message was still appearing so I uninstalled both.. anyway it worked

Comment: @yupii7 I would recommend to [edit] your post and suggest that people try uninstalling the old, system-wide one first, because this can (and should) already solve the problem. Uninstalling both and reinstalling the new one should be tried only if the first attempt fails.

Comment: "You need to uninstall them both" It says on the their website that it should auto-uninstall the other version, what a hassle. I wouldn't have bothered if I knew this. Thanks though.

Answer (score 17):

You probably have both versions installed (like I do).

To get rid of the warning, make sure you open the user-wide version. That means unpinning the one you used to have from everywhere.

Then use windows (10) search: **visual studio code** . Only the ' user-wide distribution' gets shown. If you open visual studio code that way, the warning is gone.

Comment: I uninstalled it before installing the new one and still get the message. I only have one "Visual Studio Code" in "Programs and Features". Searching **visual studio code** via the windows 10 search doesn't return any results.

Comment: @nadroev you should just uninstall the one which doesn't have `(User)` postscript

Answer (score 14):

i had these installed:

[image]

uninstalled the first one and that error message is gone.

Comment: After doing this, I lost my context menu options and default `open-as` settings for associated file types.

Comment: do you still have the other one listed in the programs? In your case you need to uninstall the other one too and then install it again. Your case maybe different then others. Its been pretty random what this change actually causes since their installation method changed from one to another.

Answer (score 6):

The new executable of the "user-wide distribution" is in this location by default:

```
C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\Code.exe
```

Replacing your shortcuts with this one should make sure you are using the new installation. (You can also uninstall the old one of course if you want to)

Answer (score 0):

Run into this issue today but all I did was install the new one one (with user extension) and then after successful installation I uninstalled the the old one. Restart my computer and all seems to be ok.

Answer (score 0):

I magically solved by (using windows 10):

1. `Unpin from "taskbar"` the vs code shortcut
2. Remove the shortcut from desktop also if you have it
3. Search on cortana "visual studio code", once the app appears right click and select "pin to taskbar"
4. Open tha vs code app from taskbar and the error should be gone.